# Is there any indication that my Android appwidget is "installed"?

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I wrote an Android app with an appwidget.

I want to do this in my code:

`if (widget_is_used_by_user)`

Is there any way for me to know whether the user placed the widget on the home screen?

Comment: what do You mean with app pages? For information about installed, there is onEnabled() method in AppWidgetProvider

Comment: ״app pages" i meant the widget is placed in home screen or other screen. meaning the user dragged the widget from the widgets list and placed it to use.

Comment: FYI, i googled. Maybe the wrong query. https://www.google.co.il/search?q=widget+is+installed+android&oq=widget+is+installed+android&aqs=chrome..69i57.4565j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8

I think your putting too much effort, you could just sent the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If You want to know if the Widget is installed, put som e Log, or whatever You want to do inside onEnabled():

```
   public void onEnabled(Context context){

    super(context);
     Log.d("WIDGET","WIDGET ENABLED);

     }
```

Also, sometimes it is required to set actions inside the receiver in manifest. I saw some posts about that, but in my widget I also get message without setting action:

```
    <intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_ENABLED" />
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DELETED" />
<action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_DISABLED" />  
    </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to keep track of them on your own like Opiatefuchs suggests, unfortunately there's no sure way.

You can query the `AppWidgetManager` to get a list of available appwidget IDs like this:

```
ComponentName widgetProvider = new ComponentName(this, "appwidget_class_name");
int[] appWidgetIds = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this).getAppWidgetIds(widgetProvider);
for (int awId : appWidgetIds) {
    // If there is any appwidget on the home screen, its ID should be in the list
}
```

I'm saying there's no sure way because the problem of *phantom* appwidget IDs (IDs created by the AppWidgetHost that have no "real" widget present on the home screen) is still a reality, even with recent Android versions.